# Hyper link issue inside ICS file

Tags: hyperlink, icalendar

I have created an ICS file. And it has a hyperlink for a text. In outlook 2013, it is working fine. But in other email clients, it is showing me the full URL along with the hyper linked text. Refer the below screenshots. 
[MAC-OS-Laptop](http://img.en25.com/EloquaImages/clients/VerticurlE10Sandbox/%7Bf98b2c74-a237-4409-91cf-a600f031a73e%7D_MAC-OS-Laptop.png)
[Outlook2016](http://img.en25.com/EloquaImages/clients/VerticurlE10Sandbox/%7B4c90fe6f-0789-43a1-b7d0-d2f8584a66e6%7D_Outlook2016.png)

This is only working fine in Outlook2013. Refer this screenshot.
[Outlook2013](http://img.en25.com/EloquaImages/clients/VerticurlE10Sandbox/%7Badaeba90-4ca8-4e96-973e-a89771786c9f%7D_Outlook2013.jpg)

Please help to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Venil, Not all calendar or email applications will cope with html in the event description.  Of course some choose to, however the specification tends to indicate that the DESCRIPTION is meant to be 'plain' text.   Some applications will convert a plain url (no hyperlink) to a clickable one.  It may be safer and cleaner to use a plain url rather than the html hyperlink.  See the RFC5545 specification links:

The [DESCRIPTION definition in the RFC5545 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.1.5) says it is of type text.  A [text type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-46) is defined as human readable.  The spec allows for an [ALTREP that may contain html.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-15)  Putting all that together implies that the DESCRIPTION field is not intended to have html.

Comment: Hi Anmari, Thanks for this. It helps me.